# @swagger-api/apidom-reference/configuration/empty' error altough I run meteor npm i swagger-ui

Tags: meteor, swagger-ui

```
meteor npm i swagger-ui
```

[after run the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0A23o.png)

still gettings same error, when I look for node_modules/@swagger-api/apidom-reference/configuration/empty ,  I see there is no "configuration" named folder

[node_modules/@swagger-ui/...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIyB6.png)

Despite I installed swagger-ui with

```
meteor npm i swagger-ui
```

I still get error and when I check the folder itself in node_modules, I see there is no folder named "configuration"